# Директива #import msvc и mingw

Tags: visual-c++, qt5, com, mingw

Здравствуйте.
Имеется проект Qt5 и библиотека dll АТОЛ для обмена с терминалами сбора данных, как я понимаю COM. В официальной документации есть пример под VC++6, в котором она подключается директивой `#import`.

```
    #import Pdx1c.dll no_namespace
    //Дальше работаем с com
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    IPDX51Ptr pPdx;
    HRESULT res = fPdx.CreateInstance("AddIn.PDX45");
    //Ну и так далее....
```

Если проект собирается **MSVC** - проблем нет. Если собирается **MINGW** - полмиллиона ошибок, оно и понятно. Вопрос: можно ли подружить подобный код с **MINGW**? Или может быть возможно использовать что-то Qt-специфичное?